# Showing a certain set is a Dedekind cut

Tags: elementary-set-theory, real-numbers

Let $\mathbf{R}\subset\mathfrak{P}(\mathbf{Q})$ be the set of all $R$ such that

1. $R\ne\emptyset$ and $\mathbf{Q}-R\ne\emptyset$;
2. $\mathbf{Q}-R=\{x\in\mathbf{Q}\ |\ (\forall r)(r\in R\implies x<r)\}$;
3. $R$ has no minimum.

Suppose $R\in\mathbf{R}$ and let $X:=\{x\in\mathbf{Q}\ |\ (\forall r)(r\in R\implies 0<x+r)\}$. I have already shown that $X$ satisfies (1) and (2). I want to prove it for (3).

Let $x\in X$. We want to find a $y\in X$ such that $y<x$. I have no idea how to look for such a $y$. Can someone please help me get this started? Only a hint will be enough.

Comment: Is it your $X$ simply all rational numbers >0? If no, then what is $R$ in $X$ definition?

Comment: I have fixed the error.

Comment: Usually 2nd axiom for cut is closed downwards or upwards - which one represent your 2nd one?

Comment: @zkutch: Since, according to requirement 2, all elements of its complement are less than the elements of the set, it must be upwards closed (I assume that the minus sign here refers to set difference, not to differences of elements).

Comment: @celtschk. Thanks. You see I am a little confused by the form of definition. I have worked on cuts with several sources, since Landau's book, and even wrote a small section about cuts for one problem book, but I see such a form for the first time. It will be interesting if OP shares source.

Comment: @zkutch The definition is taken from Analysis I (Herbert Amann and Joachim Escher).

Comment: Thanks. I was not familiar with this book.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It isn’t necessarily true that $X$ satisfies (3). Let $R=\{q\in{\bf Q}:0<q\}$; you can easily show that $R\in\bf R$. Then the associated set $X$ is

$$X=\{x\in{\bf Q}:0<x+r\text{ for each }r\in R\}\,,$$

and you can show that $0=\min X$.

More generally, $X$ will satisfy (3) if and only if ${\bf Q}\setminus R$ has no maximum, which will be the case precisely when the cut $R$ corresponds to an irrational number. When $R$ corresponds to a rational number $q$, $q$ is the maximum element of ${\bf Q}\setminus R$.